# Galaxy Tab 10.1 Serial Port Adapter

Tags: android, serial-port, adapter, galaxy, galaxy-tab

Are there pre-made serial port adapters for the Galaxy Tablet 10.1 on the market?  Or would you have to piece together something like this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 9-pin to USB adapter for the Galaxy on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0072JG9S4)

Using this, I was able to connect a standard USB to serial adapter to it and get my Galaxy synced with my device.